# Python -pip install Exception for any Libary\Package i'm trying to install

Tags: python, pip

Im using Python 2.7 on windows 8.1, using Visual Studio as f.w

Anyway,

After installing python and some packages couple of days ago, I'm unable anymore to pip install packages (Any of them -Just name it) and keep getting the exception below, which contains tens of error
P.S :
No changes were done in my environment.
I have tried to upgrade pip as well and got same error

Thanks for the help

The same error i'm getting all time:

```
----- Installing 'webdriver' -----

Collecting webdriver

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main

    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 294, in run

    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 334, in 
prepare_files

    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 321, in 
_walk_req_to_install

    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 461, in 
_prepare_file

    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 250, in 
populate_link

    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 486, in 
find_requirement

    all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 404, in 
_find_all_versions

    index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 378, in 
_get_index_urls_locations

    page = self._get_page(main_index_url)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 818, in _get_page

    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 949, in get_page

    trusted=link.trusted,

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 866, in __init__

    namespaceHTMLElements=False,

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", 
line 27, in parse

    tb = treebuilders.getTreeBuilder(treebuilder)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-
packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\treebuilders\__init__.py", line 73, in 
getTreeBuilder

    return etree.getETreeModule(implementation, **kwargs).TreeBuilder

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\utils.py", line 98, 
in moduleFactory

    objs = factory(baseModule, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-
packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\treebuilders\etree.py", line 17, in 
getETreeBuilder

    ElementTreeCommentType = ElementTree.Comment("asd").tag

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Comment'

You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.0 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' 
command.
```

Comment: Maybe `pip install --upgrade https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-8.0.2.tar.gz`?

Comment: Maybe `easy_install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Sorry non of the above helped..With lol4to suggestion I got exception at the end : windows access denied -'c:\\users\\lumos\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-cgxqx7-uninstall\\python27\\scripts\\pip.exe'